# Alternative for pycrypto package

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pycrypto package, but I got still getting an error i don't know why ?
i have python 3.9, is there any alternatives ?

As you can see bellow, this is the error that I got :

```
Collecting pycrypto Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de33889219e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
```

Thank you

Comment: It might be worth investigating that "`error`" before entirely discarding the package…?!

Comment: Also: https://www.pycrypto.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pycrypto` doesn't work with python3, you can use instead  `pycryptodome` :

```
pip install pycryptodome
```